# Assigning size_t to off_t produces sign-conversion error

Tags: c, sizeof

I'm using gcc of the following version:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
```

Consider the following simple code fragment compiled with `-Werror=sign-conversion`:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(void){
    size_t sz = sizeof(long);
    off_t off_1 = sz; //error: conversion to 'off_t' {aka 'long int'} from 'size_t' {aka 'long unsigned int'} may change the sign of the result
    off_t off_2 = sizeof(long); //compiles fine
    return 0;
}
```

[**godbolt live example**](https://godbolt.org/z/6ocKa9b85)

According to **N2596/6.5.3.4 The `sizeof` and `_Alignof` operators:**

> The value of the result of both operators is implementation-defined,
> and its type (an unsigned integer type) is `size_t`, defined in
> `<stddef.h>` (and other headers).

So it appeared to me that the result of `off_t off_1 = sz;` should be the same as off_t `off_2 = sizeof(long);`

Why does `off_t off_1 = sz;` produces this error?

Comment: OT: You can probably see the same with simpler code without use of `sizeof`. Try `size_t sz = 8; off_t off_1 = sz; off_t off_2 = (size_t)8;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line:

```
off_t off_1 = sz;
```

Is producing an error because `sz` on your system is an **unsigned** 64 bit value (`long unsigned int`), and `off_1` is a **signed** 64 bit value (`long int`).
In the general case there are values of `sz` that cannot be fitted into `off_1`.

However in this line:

```
off_t off_2 = sizeof(long);
```

`sizeof(long)` is a **compile time constant** (`8` on your system), and the compiler can verify that it can be safely assigned into `off_t off_2`.

Comment: Re "*on your system*", The C type `size_t` is always unsigned (though not always 64 bits), and the POSIX type `off_t` is always signed (though not always 64 bits).

Comment: @ikegami I thought that theoretically (although very unlikely) there could be a system where `size_t` is 32 bit unsigned, but `off_t` a 64 bit signed, and on such system the compiler should not have generated the error. This is why I menioned the current system as relevant.

Comment: And it seems that gcc is actually smart enough to warn against fishy compile-time constants - for example `off_t off_2 = 1ul << (8*sizeof(long)-1);` gives a `-Wsign-conversion` warning too.

Comment: @Lundin even more simple example of non compile time const `sizeof` will give an error https://godbolt.org/z/Te3sPK5Wx